# On Grothendieck's abstract definition of differential operators

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, differential-operators, d-modules

I have heard that there is the following abstract definition due to Grothendieck of differential operators on a module $M$ over a commutative associative unital algebra $A$ over a field of characteristic 0.
The definition is inductive in the order of differential operator.

Degree zero operators are precisely  endomorphisms of $M$ as $A$-module.

Given $f\in A$, let us denote by $\hat f\colon M\to M$ the operator of multiplication by $f$.

A linear map $D\colon M\to M$ is called differential operator of degree at most $d$ if for any $f\in A$ the commutator
$[D,\hat f]$ is differential operator of degree $d-1$.

(If $A$ is the algebra of functions on a smooth affine variety, and $M$ is a space of sections of an algebraic vector bundle then the Grothendieck's definition is equivalent to the standard one.)

> I am wondering whether this notion is considered to be useful  when $A$ might have nilpotent elements. Are there any interesting examples/ applications of such a situation?

Comment: You might consider taking a look at https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.03960v2 by Jack Jeffries a long with the references there

Comment: Indeed, the case when $A$ has nilpotent elements is essential to the theory! Check out Grothendieck's article "Crystals and the de Rham cohomology of schemes" in the collection "Dix exposes...": http://scholar.google.com/scholar_url?url=http://cm2vivi2002.free.fr/AG-biblio/AG-43.pdf&hl=en&sa=X&scisig=AAGBfm0Ci64BjfUOe_NAgqgTuIpm2M-5QQ&nossl=1&oi=scholarr Essentially, degree $d$ differential operators on $A$ are certain endomorphisms of $A \otimes A/I^d$, where $I$ is the augmentation ideal.